# Check two columns for matches then edit a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some trouble with a VBA code I am writing and am looking for some help. I am new here, if you need any more info please let me know. Also if the description isn't clear enough.

What I am trying to do:
I've got two worksheets, I want to look for matches in two columns. One column in one sheet the other column in other sheet. If there is a match I want to edit a value in the first worksheet.

**My code**

```
Private Sub
Dim fnd1 As Range
Set fnd1 = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C:C").Find(Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D:D").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) - Worksheets("Blad1").Range("H" & fnd1.Row)
Else
    MsgBox ("Error, no match")
End If

Dim fnd1 As Range
Set fnd1 = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C:C").Find(Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D:D").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) - Worksheets("Blad1").Range("H" & fnd1.Row)
Else
    MsgBox ("Error, no match")
End If
End Sub
```

The problem:
My code isn't finding any matches even though they are definitely there. I feel like the problem is in the "Set fnd1"....

Please let me know if any more info is needed! Thanks in advance....

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check the code .. appearing twice with Dim statement. Also, you need to loop through each cell in the column in the first sheet where you want to edit values. In a loop, find each cell value in second sheet column and if matched edit value before completing loop..

Comment: You're trying to find the ENTIRE column D in column C `Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D:D").Value` - you need to be looking for ONE value at a time `Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D1").Value`

Comment: It seems you are changing the values on the same row of the found cell on the other sheet. What if the rows are different?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick responses. I think Naresh's answer makes sense, I should make a loop. I was hoping it would do it automatically. I'll try it with a loop and let you know if it worked! :)

Comment: @NareshBhople I am editing values in sheet1 in row x where x is the same row in sheet2? Or editing values in sheet1 on the same row? The last would be correct and would Always be the case.

Comment: I meant if a cell on first sheet (Say C10) matches with a cell in the second sheet but on a different row (Say D15). Then your code will change in the first sheet but no on the C10 row but on D15 row.

Answer (score 0):

Trying something like this? Or may ne you need to change the sheets/ranges .. check. **Macro changes cannot be undone. Try macros on duplicate/sample data first OR close the workbook without saving changes.**

```
Sub CompareAndChange()
Dim cl As Range, fnd1 As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Lrow = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Trow As Long
Trow = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cl In Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C1:C" & Lrow)
'cl from "Voorraadlijst" C Column to be found in "Blad1" D Column

On Error Resume Next ' to handle error is the cl value not found.

    Set fnd1 = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D1:D" & Trow).Find(cl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'If found the cl value in D column of "Blad1" sheet name the cell "fnd1"

    If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & cl.Row) = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & cl.Row) _
                                                    - Worksheets("Blad1").Range("H" & fnd1.Row)
    'If cl value found then change G Column cell in "Voorraadlijst" sheet on the cl row.

    Else
    MsgBox ("Error, no match")
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, there will be problem if there are duplicate values in column D of "Blad1" sheet .as the macro will find only the first match as in case of vlookup.

Comment: Thanks, got it almost working. There can't be duplicate values in column D so that's no problem. Made a slight adjustment to compare the other way around (there's less data in "blad1"). But the part where the value is changed is not working.
 See code below:

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Worksheets("Blad1").Columns("L").Hidden = False
Range("L3").Value = "=Sumproduct(F2:F65536, H2:H65536)"
Dim dl As Range, fnd1 As Range, c1 As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Lrow = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Trow As Long
Trow = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each dl In Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D2:D" & Trow)

On Error Resume Next ' to handle error is the cl value not found.

Set fnd1 = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("C1:C" & Lrow).Find(dl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
'If found the cl value in D column of "Blad1" sheet name the cell "fnd1"

If Not fnd1 Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) = Worksheets("Voorraadlijst").Range("G" & fnd1.Row) _
                                                - Worksheets("Blad1").Range("H" & d1.Row)
'If cl value found then change G Column cell in "Voorraadlijst" sheet on the cl row.

Else
MsgBox ("Error, no match")
End If
```

Next

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For me the find method seemed to be buggy. So i always do a loop. Also easier to have conditional statements.

```
Sub findValue()

Dim arr As Variant

arr = shVoorraadlisjt.Range("D:D")

Dim valueToFind  As String
valueToFind = "Find Me"

Dim j As Integer
For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(j) = valueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Found the value")
    End If

Next j



End Sub
```

For good practice i prefer to change the worksheet code name. I hope this helps in some way!